# How to automatically highlight syntax of code in a post?

Tags: themes, posts, design, css

I post my codes from different programing languages. Now, I want to highlight syntax of codes with different colors. But, doing it manually is time consuming. Is there any plugin or method which could do this automatically? Strictly, it should be done in CSS way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a whole bunch of plugins that do that. After some reading i decided to go with [Syntax Highlighter Evolved](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/).

Answer (score 3):

There are many plugins for that mostly based on shortcodes i use either

- Google Syntax Highlighter for WordPress
  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-syntax-highlighter/
- SyntaxHighlighter Evolved 
  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/